# new to NetLogo, i recently attended a university open day and am trying to add additional function to my turtles

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get a turtle to stop if they run out of energy as if they have died. when they have eaten the grass, however keep getting an error when attempting to use an if statement.

```
turtles-own [energy]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 100
  ask turtles [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  set energy energy + 10
end


to go
  move-turtles
  eat-grass
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [ 
    if energy energy = 0 [ stop ]
    right random 360 
    forward 1 
    set energy energy - 1
  ] 
end

to eat-grass
  ask turtles [ 
    if pcolor = green [ 
      set pcolor black 
      set energy energy + 10
    ]
  ]
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have repeated the variable name energy, just replace `if energy energy = 0` with `if energy = 0`